# How to use css to put an item just above the top of the screen?

Tags: css

I'm working on a page that animates slides out of the screen. This is how I currently do it.

```
var previousOffset = ($(window).height())*-1;
previousOffset = previousOffset+'px'
$('.current').animate({
    top: previousOffset,
}, 500, function(){...}
```

I was wondering, is there a cleaner way to do it, with pure css, without measuring the height of the of the screen. Currently, the item has `position:absolute`, but that is not a requierment.

To be clear currently the css of .current is:

```
.current{
  top: -"height of screen";
  position: absolute;
}
```

I would like to do it without "height of screen".

Comment: What do you exactly want...

Comment: have you tried `.current{margin-top: -"height_of_the_slide"px;}`?

Comment: try position:fixed and kindly describe  the detail

Comment: @mrAlien, to position the item exactly above the screen.

Comment: @Joum the height of the slide equals the height of the screen, that's what I would like to get away from.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren the item should be off completely right?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that without knowing the height of the screen somehow. You'll always have to displace the slide a certain negative margin above, and that margin will be its size. I can't think of any other way to do this... Just out of curiosity, why do you need to _get away from_ finding the height of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may depend heavily on your other markup, but you could try setting the height of the `.current` element to 100% and just deal with percentages. This will implicitly handle the resizing of the window for you.

Note that you must set the html & body element to 100% for this to work.

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

.current { 
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#nextButton').click(function(){
    $('.current').animate({
        top: '-100%'
    }, 500, function(){
       // do something
    }); 
});
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/BQdtm/

Answer (score 1):

Specify the position as `fixed` then set top to the appropriate negative value.

```
.current{
    position: fixed;
    height: 10px;
    top: -10px; /* This will need adjusted */
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UH4p7/

Comment: The height of the slide equals the height of the screen, that's what I would like to get away from.